# Можно ли использовать нестандартные шрифты при верстке писем?

Tags: html, css

в макете

roboto 400

roboto 700

---

imago pro 400

imago pro 500

---

разве при верстке писем не используются только страндартные шрифты?

тоесть *imago pro и roboto* впринципе не подходят

Comment: да, только стандартные. Можешь попробовать какие-то другие, но в большинстве почтовых клиентов они слетят

Comment: @VladykoD, а можно использовать display: block для ссылок и спанов?

Comment: скорее всего да. Не могу сказать точнее, давно не занималась. Возможно, тебе поможет https://mjml.io/try-it-live тут автоматически собираются многие блоки.